# Is there a way to recursively make an array with every powers of two, given the array length?

Tags: arrays, recursion, processing

I'm trying to make a program where you recursively set an array index to 2^index. So far, I have this:

```
void powersOf2(int[] array) {
  powersOf2(array, 0);
}

void powersOf2(int[] array, int i) {
  if (array.length == 1) {
    array[0] = 1;
  } else {
    if (i != array.length) {
      for (int n = 0; n <= i - 1; n++) {
        array[n] *= 2;
      }
    
      powersOf2(array, i + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

But currently, it's returning this:
Say, for example, you have powersOf2(array, 0); (array.length = 3). It's supposed to return [1, 2, 4], but instead, it returns [8, 4, 2].

How can I fix this?

Comment: I absolutely love recursion and usually jump on any opportunity to use it (except at work for obvious reasons), but I'm not sure what you're trying to to here. Am I right in thinking that the array will contain it's index^2 for each position in it? Or is it 2^index? If not, please elaborate further (or wait a little, there are clever people who will get it here).

Comment: If you want me to explain it, I can say it like this:

Comment: The function given to me is supposed to return 2^n for every array, for example in index 0 (Start), it would give 1 (2^0 = 1). Index 1 will return 2 (2^1 = 2), and so on and so forth

Answer (score 0):

Recursive methods are characterized by one thing: they call themselves. Optionally, you should also make sure that you have an exit condition, or else you're creating an infinite recursive loop:

[image: Recursion meme]

The thing with recursion is that there are only few places where it really makes sense to use it. It's a dangerous thing both because it's more clever in theory than in practice, and also because in a workplace a lot of people won't work right with recursive algorithms. And, lastly, most times it'll use more resources than using an iterative algorithm to do the same exact thing.

To illustrate what I just warned you about, here are 2 ways to implement the "getting an array with powers of 2 of the index at every position" thing, but once with an iterative algorithm and once with a recursive algorithm. It's really easy to get what I meant then: you don't even need comments to get how the iterative method works, while the other one needs some brain power even if it's not very complicated.

Of course, there are a bazillion ways to implement this, so this is only the first one that came to my mind.

```
void setup(){
  float[] iterativeArray = getIterativePowersOf2(6);
  float[] recursiveArray = getRecursivePowersOf2(6);
  
  println("The Iterative array:");
  for(int i = 0; i<iterativeArray.length; i++) {
    println(i + " -> " + iterativeArray[i]);
  }
  
  println("The Recursive array:");
  for(int i = 0; i<recursiveArray.length; i++) {
    println(i + " -> " + recursiveArray[i]);
  }
}

// the iterative option
float[] getIterativePowersOf2(int arrayLength) {
  float[] array = new float[arrayLength];
  
  for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = pow(2, i);
  }
  
  return array;
}

// the recursive option
// this overload is just to make the initial call easier
float[] getRecursivePowersOf2(int arrayLength) {
  return getRecursivePowersOf2(new float[arrayLength], 0);
}
// this is where the magic happens
float[] getRecursivePowersOf2(float[] array, int index) {
  if(index < array.length) {
    // the method calls itself recursively, adding 1 to the current index every time
    // which means that it'll eventually reach the end of the array's length
    array = getRecursivePowersOf2(array, index+1);
    // then it fills the last spot in the array
    array[index] = pow(2, index);
  }
  
  // and at last it returns the array with one more spot filled, creating a cascade of filling spots in the array until thay are all filled
  // the exit condition being the first if check: 'index < array.length'
  // once the program gets to the last spot in the array, it stops calling itself
  return array;
}
```

Hope it helps, let me know if you have questions. Have fun!